# Ionic and ionic view: show background image

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

in ionic 1.2 i want show a full background image.
I have a classic project structure:

```
-hooks
-platfroms
-plugins
-resources
-scss
-www
   -css
   -img
   -js
   -lib
   -templates
   ...
```

I have a html page

```
<ion-view id="login"  hide-nav-bar="true">
   <ion-content padding="true" scroll="false">
   ...
   ...
```

Where:

```
#login {
     background: #1c2627 url("../img/live.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
```

defined in /www/css/style.css

With the command ionic serve, the background is showed correctly but in ionic view (executing the command ionic upload), the background is not showed.

What's the problem?

Comment: What is your android version? It could just be a bug in Ionic view, as it is still just in beta. Please try it on a an android device.

Answer (score 0):

I have working implementation with the exact CSS you had plus some additional code.

Try adding

```
position: fixed
top: 0
z-index: -1
height: 100%
width: 100%
```

Please note the approach.

The selector was not applied to ion-content but instead to a div that is declared outside ion-content as a sibling and child of ion-view

```
ion-view
    ion-content
    /ion-content
    div
    /div
ion-view
```